# Using aws cli to add send message permission for SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm trying to set up an existing SQS Queue as a subscriber to an SNS topic. In the AWS console in the permissions tab, I can set the policy document to

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:7670234568007:stdsourcequeue/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:7670234568007:stdsourcequeue",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:7670234568007:new_posts"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do this using the aws-cli

Answer (score 0):

These are generally managed via the CLI  command of [add-permission](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/add-permission.html) for SQS.

However as you're using your own custom policy the AWS documentation states the following

> AddPermission generates a policy for you. You can use `SetQueueAttributes` to upload your policy.

This would be accessible via the [set-queue-attributes](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sqs/set-queue-attributes.html) function.

Your policy will need to be be converted into a JSON file, against the key value of `Policy`.

As a word of caution by doing this it will **replace** the policy attached to your SQS queue, so make sure to validate it before hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **practical example** of how to do it using [set-queue-attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/set-queue-attributes.html):

```
cat >/tmp/sqs_polcy << EOL
{
    "Policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Id\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:7670234568007:stdsourcequeue\/SQSDefaultPolicy\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"sqs:SendMessage\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:7670234568007:stdsourcequeue\",\"Condition\":{\"ArnEquals\":{\"aws:SourceArn\":\"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:7670234568007:new_posts\"}}}]}"
}
EOL

aws sqs set-queue-attributes \
    --queue-url https://<your-queue-url> \
    --attributes file:///tmp/sqs_polcy
```

Above I create `/tmp/sqs_polcy` file with the policy, which is required for the `set-queue-attributes` command.

Your policy **must be stringified** from json, before you can use in the CLI command.